# How to make these containers fit when resizing the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm playing around with a site for a friend, and I'm having issues making things fit when resizing the window.

Normal:
[Looks as it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUbXV.jpg)
Smaller window:
[Gap under image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EZLL.jpg)

A gap appears under the image - ideally I want the image to resize when the window does.

Here's the HTML and CSS

```
<section id="home-info" class="bg-light">
        <div class="info-img"></div>
        <div class="info-content">
          <h2>About <span class="text-primary">133</span> Grand Rue</h2>
          <p>
            TEXT
          </p>
          <a href="about.html" class="btn">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="features">
        <div class="box bg-light">
        <i class="fas fa-mountain-sun fa-3x"></i>               
        <h3>Great Location</h3>
            <p>Sitting in the centre of St Jean du Gard, with access to the town centre.....</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box bg-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-person-swimming fa-3x"></i>
        <h3>Pool</h3>
        <p>Access to the garden and pool for the downstairs apartment.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box bg-light">
        <i class="fas fa-question fa-3x"></i>
        <h3>?</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eveniet, officiis.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
```

CSS:

```
#home-info {
    height: 400px;
  }
  
  #home-info .info-img {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: url('../img/archway.jpg') no-repeat;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    
  }
  
  #home-info .info-content {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    
  }
  
  #home-info .info-content p {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
/* Features */

.box{
    float:left;
    width: 33.333%;
    padding:60px;
    text-align:center;
}

.box i{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

tried to play around with widths and heights etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space is happening because the image is not filling its container fully when the screen resizes. When you use the `float` property, it takes the element out of the normal flow of the document. I would use flex for this section.

Setting the flexbox children to `flex: 1`, you ensure the image grows and shrinks properly with the container. This is a shorthand property in flexbox that sets `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`. [See the complete guide to flexbox here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

See below:

```css
#home-info {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
}

#home-info .info-img {
  flex: 1;
  background: url('../img/archway.jpg') no-repeat;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}

#home-info .info-content {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#home-info .info-content p {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

/* Features */

.box {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box i {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
}

.bg-light {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.bg-primary {
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Media Query for mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #home-info {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
  }

  #home-info .info-img,
  #home-info .info-content,
  .box {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="home-info" class="bg-light">
        <div class="info-img"></div>
        <div class="info-content">
          <h2>About <span class="text-primary">133</span> Grand Rue</h2>
          <p>
            TEXT
          </p>
          <a href="about.html" class="btn">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="features">
        <div class="box bg-light">
        <i class="fas fa-mountain-sun fa-3x"></i>               
        <h3>Great Location</h3>
            <p>Sitting in the centre of St Jean du Gard, with access to the town centre.....</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box bg-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-person-swimming fa-3x"></i>
        <h3>Pool</h3>
        <p>Access to the garden and pool for the downstairs apartment.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box bg-light">
        <i class="fas fa-question fa-3x"></i>
        <h3>?</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eveniet, officiis.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: That's helped a lot thank you.